# Which graphics chip on MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, graphics

My MacBook Pro has two graphics chips and automatically switches between them. How can I tell which one is currently in use? I'm just curious really; it's plenty fast enough whatever it's doing by default!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[gfxCardStatus](http://codykrieger.com/gfxCardStatus/) is a free app that lives in your menu bar. When you click it, it tells you which graphics card you're using. It also has a beta feature that lets you manually switch to one or the other.

Hope it serves you well.

Comment: That's excellent, thank you. Didn't come up in a Google search, which is odd...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use separate software to check which graphics are being used.

Such information is provided by the **System Profiler** of OS X which you can access in two ways:

1. Menubar → Apple → <kbd>⌥</kbd>-click System Information) → Graphics/Displays
2. Terminal:

   ```
   system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType
   ```

**Only one GPU has the extra section "Displays, Color LCD". This GPU is the one that is currently in use.**

e.g. In the first picture discrete graphics (ATI Radeon HD) are being used. In the second, integrated graphics (Intel HD 3000) are being used.

[image] [image]